# Calculate Difference Between All Dates Only Within Duplicate ID's

Tags: r

I have a dataset full of ID's that transfer for an individual diagnosed with an STI. For example, if person 1 has multiple bacterial STI infections, their ID remains the same for each diagnosis. What I am trying to do is determine whether the individual who is infected is simultaneously co-infected with a disease vs obtaining a different, new infection. I have created a mock dataset below.

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3),
  Disease = c("Chlamydia", "Syphilis", "Chlamydia", "Chlamydia", "Gonorrhea", "Chlamydia"),
  Date = as.Date(c("2023-01-25", "2023-01-25", "2023-07-13", "2023-03-16", "2023-04-02", "2023-08-29"))
)

df

> df
  ID   Disease       Date
1  1 Chlamydia 2023-01-25
2  1  Syphilis 2023-01-25
3  1 Chlamydia 2023-07-13
4  2 Chlamydia 2023-03-16
5  3 Gonorrhea 2023-04-02
6  3 Chlamydia 2023-08-29
```

Ideally, I would like to create a new variable that will flag if there is an incident within the same ID within a certain amount of time, say, within the same month. Ideally, the output would look like this.

```
  ID   Disease       Date Flag
1  1 Chlamydia 2023-01-25 TRUE
2  1  Syphilis 2023-01-25 TRUE
3  1 Chlamydia 2023-07-13 FALSE
4  2 Chlamydia 2023-03-16 FALSE
5  3 Gonorrhea 2023-04-02 FALSE
6  3 Chlamydia 2023-08-29 FALSE
```

So the code would identify duplicate ID's (1 and 3 in the df above), and flag if the date is within a one month period. It does not necessarily need to be a binary flag variable, but some way to allow me to filter out the co-infections (where Flag == T) data if possible.

I am a little new to coding so if you use difficult code (broad term, I know...), would you mind briefly explaining? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `diff()` to compare each date in an ID group, and check if the span falls within a set `window` value.

```
library(tidyverse)

window <- 30 # incident window, in days

df |> 
  group_by(ID) |> 
  mutate(incident_in_window = ifelse(
           Date == max(Date), # last date in a group takes FALSE as default
           list(FALSE), 
           map(list(diff(Date)), \(x) any(x <= lubridate::days(window)))
          )) |> 
  unnest(incident_in_window)

# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID Disease   Date       incident_in_window
  <dbl> <chr>     <date>     <lgl>             
1     1 Chlamydia 2023-01-25 TRUE              
2     1 Syphilis  2023-01-25 TRUE              
3     1 Chlamydia 2023-07-13 FALSE             
4     2 Chlamydia 2023-03-16 FALSE             
5     3 Gonorrhea 2023-04-02 FALSE             
6     3 Chlamydia 2023-08-29 FALSE
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help! I would upvote but do not have the reputation, so sorry. Would you mind if I asked what the map(list(....)) line of code is doing? I am having a little trouble "translating it to English".

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

mutate(df, Flag = if_else(as.yearmon(Date) == first(as.yearmon(Date)), TRUE, FALSE), .by = ID)

  ID   Disease       Date  Flag
1  1 Chlamydia 2023-01-25  TRUE
2  1  Syphilis 2023-01-25  TRUE
3  1 Chlamydia 2023-07-13 FALSE
4  2 Chlamydia 2023-03-16  TRUE
5  3 Gonorrhea 2023-04-02  TRUE
6  3 Chlamydia 2023-08-29 FALSE
```

Logically, the first case of every ID should be true.

The logic is to mutate the data frame by adding a new variable in which, by each ID, if the year and month of the date of each case is the same a the first case, the Flag is true, else false.

Comment: Awesome thank you. As stated above, I would upvote but lack the reputation, sorry friend.

Comment: You can accept a proposed answer as the solution.